# Simulating click for jQuery UI menu?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, click, simulate, jquery-ui-menu

I'm trying to simulate a click on a jQuery UI menu.  It doesn't work. Maybe I'm not referencing it properly?

This works for me:

```
 $('#test').click(function(){ console.log('test'); });
 $('#test').click();
```

This will log 'test'.  However it will not trigger the jQuery UI menu.  Are there any extra steps I have to take?

Comment: did you initialize the jquery ui menu on your selector?

Comment: Can you post the code where you set up your menu? It's difficult to know what's happening without it - as you say, `click()` would normally work fine.

Comment: i am new to using jquery ui.  how do i initialize it on my selector?

Answer (score 0):

You must initialize the plugin on your selector, which jquery menu plugin are you using?

Here is an example of initializing the jQuery UI Dialog Widget/Plugin on a selector.

```
$('#myDiv').dialog({
    title:'My Dialog'
});
```

Comment: how do you intialize the plugin on your selector?  can you give me an example?

Comment: What plugin are you using? I can create an example with that plugin